# Negation sentence in prolog

Tags: prolog

How do we add negation in prolog. eg:- input,  I am coming to class, and the Output should give, I am not coming to class. can someone please explain me these step by step, I'm.very new to prolog, Thanks

Comment: First you need to identify which term claims the relevant fact, then negate it. You could say `NOT I`, `NOT am`, `NOT coming`, `NOT to`, `NOT class`. The result you want is `I am NOT coming to class`. What you are negating is `coming` instead of say `Someone not me is coming to class` or `I am going to go somewhere else that isn't class`.

Comment: I'm sorry @G_V, I can't make a sense of what you said. Do you mean that ChaOs Titan needs to think about their logical representation?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x In a way, yes, if by logical representation you mean what each term within a structure represents. There's the obvious logical connectives such as `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`, but what they affect are terms that make up a sentence. If we were to negate 'to' instead of 'coming', you'd get `I am coming from class`. Coming indicates movement, to indicates the direction in relation to the point class. `I` indicates who or what, `am` indicates the time-frame. `You will come to class` has the exact same sentence structure, but I've swapped out some terms to drastically change the meaning.

Comment: I meant that there are different logical representations - for example we could define a predicate, that relates subject and object e.g. `come(i,to(class))`. In this case negation could only apply to the whole atom but not e.g. to class. @Isabelle Newbie already mentioned another representation: just a list of words, where the second must be the predicate. Which one is appropriate still needs to be answered by the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
sentence_negated(Sentence, NegatedSentence) :-
    Sentence = [Subject, Copula | Rest],
    NegatedSentence = [Subject, Copula, not | Rest].
```

You can use this like this:

```
?- sentence_negated([i, am, coming, to, class], NegatedSentence).
NegatedSentence = [i, am, not, coming, to, class].

?- sentence_negated(Sentence, [i, am, not, being, helpful]).
Sentence = [i, am, being, helpful].
```

But this is almost certainly not what you want. Please update your question with more detail, explain what you know about Prolog, and show us what you have tried. This is not a homework service, and it is *especially* not a homework service for incompletely specified homework.